# Logarithmic Function Behaivour

Tags: convex-optimization

I have read about Logarithmic function. We can use the second-order condition to show that the $f(x)=\log_2(1+x), x \geq 0$ is a concave function. Now, is $g(x)$ a concave function? How can I prove this fact? 
\begin{equation}
g(x)=(1-\frac{x}{a})\sum_{k=1}^K \log_2(1+\frac{b_kx}{-c_kx^2+d_kx+e_k}), \quad x \in [0,a] , \quad a>1 , \quad \forall k \in\{1,\ldots,K\}, \quad b_k,c_k,d_k,e_k>0
\end{equation}
where $a,b_k,c_k,d_k,e_k$ are positive constants and $d_k$ , $e_k$ for all $k$ are enough large so that $-c_kx^2d_kx+e_k>0$.

Comment: Please: Write $\log_2(1+x)$, not $log_2(1+x)$.  It is coded as \log_2(1+x).  The backslash not only prevents italicization but also provides proper spacing in things like $a\log b$ and $a\log(b)$ (notice that the latter has less space to the right of $\log$ than the former has). $\qquad$

Comment: Convexity is the exception, rather than the rule. In my experience, If you can't figure out how to prove convexity, it's almost certainly not.

Comment: Michael Hardy: Ok. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Michael Grant: I think $g(x)$ is a concave function. For specific values of constants, the plot of the function confirms this fact. But I don't know the mathematical proof.